# /~username not pointing to public_html

Tags: cpanel, whm

I am having an issue where http://51.38.68.201/~configsql/ is not pointing to the users public_html folder.

Is there a setting in the WHM panel I need to enable for this to work?

edit: i was under the impression that this was default.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to WHM >>> Security Center>> Apache mod_userdir Tweak
In the line for you domain click on the checkbox in the "Exclude Protection" column.

Click "Save" at the bottom of de page.